# Receive TypeError when trying to upload an image to Cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I have been trying to upload an image straight from my form to cloudinary.
Whenever I try to upload an image, I receive the following error message:

```
/mnt/c/NodeApps/uploadFile/node_modules/multer-storage-cloudinary/lib/index.js:67
    var stream = _this.cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload_stream(params, cb);
                                         ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'uploader' of undefined
    at /mnt/c/NodeApps/uploadFile/node_modules/multer-storage-cloudinary/lib/index.js:67:42
    at end (/mnt/c/NodeApps/uploadFile/node_modules/run-parallel/index.js:18:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

My form:

```html
<form action='upload' method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='text' name='caption' placeholder="Name the image">
    <input type="file" name="new_image">
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

From app.js

```
var multer                  = require('multer');
var cloudinary              = require('cloudinary').v2;
var cloudinaryStorage       = require('multer-storage-cloudinary');
var bodyParser              = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

The Cloudinary config:

```
cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.cloud_name,
    api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.API_SECRET
});

var storage = cloudinaryStorage({
    cloudinary: cloudinary,
    folder: "demo",
    allowedFormats: ['jpg', 'png'],
});
var parser = multer({ storage: storage });
```

My Post route:

```
app.post('/upload', parser.single('new_image'), (req, res) => {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err); }
        image.url = result.secure_url;
        console.log(image.url);
    });
});
```

I am totally stumped trying to resolve this error, any advice on where I am going wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you overlooked a small mistake - you already traversed into the v2 object of the SDK when you require it here:

```
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
```

So, in this code:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path, (err, result) => {
    ...
}
```

You are actually calling `cloudinary.v2.v2.uploader` instead of `cloudinary.v2.uploader`. Thus the error that it can't call the uploader method on undefined, since `cloudinary.v2.v2` is undefined. Either remove the `.v2` in your require line or from where you call uploader.

---

A separate issue is that it looks like you are going to be double-uploading images, based on your code. Since you have configured multer to use Cloudinary as the storage destination, having it as the middleware should mean that it uploads to Cloudinary by itself, so when you are calling `.uploader.upload()`, that would actually be a second upload. I believe this would be more correct code:

```
app.post('/upload', parser.single('new_image'), (req, res) => {
    // Since multer is the middleware & set to single, req.file should be an object with the results from cloudinary
    let image = {};
    image.url = req.file.secure_url;
    console.log(image.url);
});
```

---

Some references I found helpful:

- [multer-storage-cloudinary readme](https://github.com/affanshahid/multer-storage-cloudinary)
- [sample code on dev.to](https://dev.to/jakzaizzat/how-to-store-image-in-cloudinary-nodejs-rest-53od)